# jQuery image hover display caption with default state

Tags: jquery

I am stuck on how to do this efficiently. As you can tell, I'm learning how to work with jQuery but would love some help on how to do this efficiently and accurately.

Currently, on my jsfiddle demo, I would love for the center image (#2) to be highlighted and "on" when the page loads. If someone hovers over another image, the default (#2 on) would go dark and the other image would become full color and the caption  would display (as is in the demo now, but again, not efficiently coded). Then when someone hovers out of all of them, I'd love for the default to come back into play.

If someone has suggestions for better programming, it would be much appreciated. I realize my current code is not up to par.

Current fiddle demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/girdyshapiro/o8sky7v2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery(".box.two .darken img").css("opacity","1");
                    jQuery(".box.two .caption").css("color","rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");


                    jQuery(".box.three .darken img").mouseenter( function (){
                            jQuery(".box.two .darken img").css("opacity","0.5");
                            jQuery(".box.two .caption").css("color","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");

                            });

                    jQuery(".box.two .darken img").mouseenter( function (){
                            jQuery(".box.two .darken img").css("opacity","0.5");
                            jQuery(".box.two .caption").css("color","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");

                            });

                    jQuery(".box.two .darken img").mouseout( function (){
                            jQuery(".box.two .darken img").css("opacity","0.5");
                            jQuery(".box.two .caption").css("color","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)");

                            });
                    jQuery(".box.two .darken img").mouseenter( function (){
                            jQuery(".box.two .darken img").css("opacity","1");
                            jQuery(".box.two .caption").css("color","rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");

                            });



            });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to define two different states (default and active), then apply the class with jQuery

### CSS

```
.box img {
opacity: 0.5;
}
.box .caption {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.box.active img {
opacity: 1;
}
.box.active .caption {
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

### JS

```
var defaultItem = jQuery(".box.two");

var reset = function (resetAll) {//if resetAll is false, highlight the default item
    jQuery(".box").removeClass('active');
    if(!resetAll) {
        setActive(defaultItem);
    }

}

var setActive = function (el) {
    el.addClass('active');
}

jQuery(".box").on('mouseenter', function () {
    reset(true);
    setActive(jQuery(this));
});


jQuery(".box").on('mouseleave', function () {
    reset(); //comment this line if you want the box to be active since mouse pointer goes over another box
});

reset();
```

Comment: Awesome idea and thanks for the suggestion. I'll try this right now!

Comment: Alright, that code is so much cleaner. The only thing I'm having a problem with right now is having the active state on mouseleave to default to the .box.two. I'll setup another jsfiddle to show how I have your code implemented.

Comment: I think I just figured it out, but please feel free to tell me a better way to adjust the code.

Comment: I added a line to your line above the setActive line: `jQuery(".industries .box").on('mouseleave', function () {
        reset(); //comment this line if you want the box to be active since mouse pointer goes over another box
        setActive(jQuery(".industries .box.two"));
        });`

Comment: I edited the answer. The selectors you use are more specific; only ".box" elements inside an ".industries" container. For the sake of semplicity, I wrote a single class both in CSS and JS. If you need more specific selectors, feel free to change the code (both CSS and JS :) )